# Power Query Not Loading Correctly Into Table

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, powerquery

I created a query for source data connected to a Sharepoint folder. The data loads correctly in the Preview Query Editor but once I load it into a table on the worksheet, the rows are misarranged and some values are zeroed out. How do I fix this and get it to load as per the Preview?

[Preview with "Do Not Delete" rows and Sample File going first]

[image]

[Actual Loaded Table with Zeroed out values and missing rows on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlImD.png)

Have tried refreshing already, recreating the query, reloading it, reuploading my data, but nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, and paste in the code you are using from home...advanced editor...  Thanks

Comment: Did you sort by one or multiple columns in PowerQuery?
For zeroed columns, set a type to your columns and replace null by the value you want (empty string for example)?